# Most efficient way of converting BigQuery json from API to a CSV

Tags: powershell, api, google-bigquery

Good morning/afternoon everyone,

When you run a query against Google BigQuery API, you get a response in a JSON file that's structured in a weird way.

You can find column names in `$ColumnName = $Response.schema.fields.name` but the values for the columns are in `$Row = $Response.rows`.

Here's what rows looks like:

```
{
        "f":  [
                  "@{v=@2019-11-04 14:14:49}",
                  "@{v=@8349531079148439128}",
                  "@{v=Returning Visitor}",
                  "@{v=1}",
                  "@{v=Yes}",
                  "@{v=Good news!}",
                  "@{v=1}",
                  "@{v=0}",
                  "@{v=1}",
                  "@{v=google}",
                  "@{v=organic}",
                  "@{v=(not set)}",
                  "@{v=(not provided)}",
                  "@{v=mobile}",
                  "@{v=/}",
                  "@{v=/}",
                  "@{v=No}",
                  "@{v=Yes}",
                  "@{v=No}"
              ]
    },
    {
        "f":  [
                  "@{v=@2019-11-04 08:52:48}",
                  "@{v=@3602395308467676896}",
                  "@{v=New Visitor}",
                  "@{v=4a9bcd67a01d}",
                  "@{v=Yes}",
                  "@{v=We\u0027re happy to carry out the work.}",
                  "@{v=}",
                  "@{v=1}",
                  "@{v=0}",
                  "@{v=ivr}",
                  "@{v=sms}",
                  "@{v=ivr-deflect}",
                  "@{v=(not set)}",
                  "@{v=mobile}",
                  "@{v=/}",
                  "@{v=/}",
                  "@{v=Yes}",
                  "@{v=No}",
                  "@{v=No}"
              ]
    }
```

So every row is assigned to "f" and values of each column is assigned to "v", inside of "f".

So to get them in the right format I wrote a pair of loops below:

```bsh
$Data = @()
for($j=0; $j -lt $RowCount; $j++){
    $Datarow = New-Object PSObject
    For($i=0; $i -lt $ColumnCount; $i++){
        $Datarow | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name $ColumnName[$i] -Value $Row[$j].f.v[$i]
    }
    $Data += $Datarow
}
```

But as you can imagine, it's quote slow. Especially on our a bit aged server machine where it will be scheduled.

**Do you know of better ways of doing it?**

Regards, Jarek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to speed up your code:

- Avoid incrementally "extending" your array with `+=`, because that requires creating a *new* array behind the scenes in every iteration; instead, use the `for` loop as an *expression* and let *PowerShell* collect its output in an array for you.
- Avoid the costly `New-Object` and `Add-Member` calls by first creating the property-value pairs in an *ordered hashtable* (which is much faster) and afterwards casting that hashtble to `[pscustomobject]` in order to convert it to a custom object (PSv3+).

```
$Data = 
  for ($j=0; $j -lt $RowCount; $j++){
      $Datarow = [ordered] @{} # an ordered hashtable that represents a row.
      For($i=0; $i -lt $ColumnCount; $i++){
        $Datarow[$ColumnName[$i]] = $Row[$j].f.v[$i]
      }
      [pscustomobject] $Datarow # convert to a custom object and output.
  }
```

*Update*: Jarek (the OP) reports that this solution is about 3 times faster than the original one.
Without the `[pscustomobject]` cast - i.e., by using the hashtable instances directly - the factor is about 5, but note that you currently (as of PowerShell Core 7.0.0-preview.5) cannot use hashtables with `Export-Csv` / `ConvertTo-Csv`.
Adding support for that is the subject of [this feature request on GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10999).

Comment: Thanks, @JarekSzczyg - answer updated. Note that I've added a link to a feature request to make `Export-Csv` / `ConvertTo-Csv` support hashtables (dictionaries), the way `ConvertTo-Json` already does. If you would also like to see this feature, please give it a thumbs-up on GitHub.